# Regular Expression for any characters between a text

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on a C# application need a regular experssion for following scenario any help would be really appreciated.

Text between `\Network Interface` and `\Bytes Sent/sec` can be different, how to identify the match using regular expression?

> \Network Interface **virtual machine** \Bytes Sent/sec
>
> \Network Interface **non virtual machine 1** \Bytes Sent/sec
>
> \Network Interface **non virtual machine 2** \Bytes Sent/sec

Comment: Personally, I would not use a regular expression. Instead, I would do a substring search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\\Network Interface (.*) \\Bytes Sent/sec
```

Comment: Took the liberty of escaping your backslashes